# @preact/signals-react not working in Vite application

Tags: reactjs, vite, preact-signal

I have a basic application in Vite.
Why can't I type in the `input` field?

```
import React from "react";
import { signal, computed } from "@preact/signals-react";

const name = signal<string>("");
const disabled = computed<boolean>(() => name.value.trim() === "");

const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name.value} onInput={e => (name.value = e.currentTarget.value)} />
      <p>Name: {name.value}</p>
      <p>Disabled: {disabled.value ? "true" : "false"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: Please read [the instructions](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#react-integration). As of v2 the React integration does not use automatic tracking.